# cannot ping website but can ping ip, DNS not working

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

I am using an ARM target running Open Embedded Linux from Yocto, it has `eth0` network interface from a private LAN network.

I am able to ping an IP like `173.203.44.122` but using the name(`rackspace.com`) I am unable to ping

```
root@ABC:~# ping 173.203.44.122
PING 173.203.44.122 (173.203.44.122): 56 data bytes 
64 bytes from 173.203.44.122: seq=0 ttl=236 time=10.502 ms
64 bytes from 173.203.44.122: seq=1 ttl=236 time=10.569 ms
64 bytes from 173.203.44.122: seq=2 ttl=236 time=10.431 ms

--- 173.203.44.122 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 10.431/10.500/10.569 ms
root@ABC:~# ping rackspace.com
ping: bad address 'rackspace.com'
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` has the following configuration:

```
nameserver 173.203.4.8
nameserver 173.203.4.9
```

Please let me know what else needs to be checked.

Comment: use google ns:  `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: I am unable to ping 8.8.8.8, it just hangs and i do see that /etc/resolv.conf gets overwritten with some other values without reboot, may be from dhclient

Comment: what do `nslookup rackspace.com` and `dig rackspace.com` say?

Comment: `nslookup: can't resolve 'rackspace.com'` but for microsoft.com nslookup returns `Name:      microsoft.com
Address 1: 104.40.211.35
Address 2: 104.43.195.251
Address 3: 23.100.122.175
Address 4: 23.96.52.53
Address 5: 191.239.213.197` but the ping does not work on the ip for microsoft.com

Comment: i don't have dig on the target

Comment: Is there a firewall on that private network? Often pinging is blocked on enterprise networks, as well as some name resolutions (though rackspace would be weird)...

Comment: Is your private network hosted by Rackspace? If not, why are you trying to use Rackspace DNS?

Comment: no, I am just trying to resolve rackspace.com by using either my private network's DNS or a public DNS like 173.203.4.8, public DNS is never working and my private DNS is working only  for few websites

Comment: 173.203.4.8 is clearly not an open recursive nameserver. So you should not use it if you are not one of its customer. Otherwise you will not get reply from it you need to have your DNS resolution working.

Comment: Do not use 8.8.8.8 just by lazyness. Use your correct ISP/hosting company nameservers or install a resolving nameserver directly on your server.

Answer (score -1):

On your network interface add the following line in your network interface

```
iface eth0 inet static
         address 192.168.142.44
         netmask 255.255.0.0
         gateway 192.168.0.1
         # Space-separated DNS servers
         dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Edit be /etc/resolv.conf with the DNS of your choice, and then run the following command on the file.

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

The above command blocks writing to the file, to unlock execute

```
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: There should never be a need to `chattr` the `/etc/resolv.conf` file